# nouislider step don't work with multiple range

Tags: javascript, reactjs, slider, nouislider

everything works on a scale from 100 to 1000, but after 1000 the step stops working, tell me what can be done?

[image: n]

```
<Nouislider
range={{
  'min': 100,
  '25%': 1000,
  '50%': 10000,
  '75%': 100000,
  'max': 1000000
}}
pips={{
  mode: 'values',
  values: [100, 1000, 10000, 100000, 1000000],
  density: 10
}}
start={[100, 1000000]}
tooltips
connect
step={100}
format={wNumb({
  decimals: 0
})}
/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `step` option only applies to the first part of the range. For the subsequent parts, you can pass an array for each individual range values.

For example:

```
range: {
    'min': [0],
    '10%': [500, 500],
    '50%': [4000, 1000],
    'max': [10000]
}
```

[Here's the relevant part of the documentation.](https://refreshless.com/nouislider/slider-values/#section-non-linear-step).